# Laravel nest divs in loop

Tags: php, laravel

I want to nest divs in a loop like this

```
<div>
 Content
  <div>
   Content
    <div>
     Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am thinking of recursion but I am not sure how to implement it in blade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `include` to call the nested content in Blade:

example.blade.php:

```
<div>
    {{ $content->data }}
    @if ($content->hasNestedData())
        @include('viewfolder.example', $content->nestedContent)
    @endif
</div>
```

To check for nested content, you could implement a function in your model like this:

```
public function hasNestedData()
{
    return $this->nestedContent !== null;
}
```

And set the nested content as an attribute, for example:

```
public function nestedContent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Content::class, 'nested_content_id');
}
```

As you didn't post the code you already have, use this as the main idea.